# Filtrar resultados de una sentencia por dia, semana y mes de acuerdo a la fecha en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas

Ventas:

```
CREATE TABLE `ventas` (
  `id_venta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `ventas` (`id_venta`, `id_usuario`, `fecha`) VALUES
(1, 2, '2020-04-25 06:33:56'),
(2, 2, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(3, 2, '2020-02-28 15:33:56'),
(4, 3, '2020-02-03 15:33:56'),
(5, 3, '2020-01-07 15:33:56'),
(6, 4, '2020-05-25 15:33:56'),
(7, 4, '2020-04-27 15:33:56'),
(8, 5, '2020-03-16 15:33:56'),
(9, 5, '2017-12-05 15:33:56'),
(10, 6, '2020-01-15 15:33:56'),
(11, 7, '2019-11-09 15:33:56'),
(12, 7, '2019-10-05 15:33:56'),
(13, 7, '2020-05-12 15:33:56'),
(14, 7, '2020-01-28 15:33:56'),
(15, 8, '2020-03-01 15:33:56'),
(16, 9, '2020-04-17 15:33:56'),
(17, 10, '2020-02-09 15:33:56'),
(18, 11, '2019-11-05 15:33:56'),
(19, 11, '2020-02-12 15:33:56'),
(20, 11, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(21, 11, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(22, 11, '2020-04-26 15:33:56'),
(23, 1, '2020-05-05 15:33:56'),
(24, 2, '2020-05-05 21:40:58');
```

Detalle ventas:

```
CREATE TABLE `detalle_ventas` (
  `id_venta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_producto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio` double NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `detalle_ventas` (`id_venta`, `id_producto`, `precio`, `cantidad`) VALUES
(1, 2, 18000.9, 1),
(1, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(1, 1, 40000, 2),
(2, 3, 25000, 1),
(3, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(4, 6, 12000, 1),
(4, 8, 7000, 2),
(4, 11, 5400, 1),
(5, 14, 560, 1),
(6, 10, 2300.56, 3),
(6, 13, 230, 2),
(6, 12, 300, 1),
(7, 16, 17000, 1),
(8, 4, 4898.99, 3),
(8, 1, 40000, 3),
(8, 9, 1000, 1),
(8, 10, 2300.56, 2),
(8, 15, 430, 2),
(9, 3, 25000, 1),
(10, 3, 25000, 4),
(11, 6, 12000, 2),
(12, 1, 40000, 1),
(13, 14, 560, 1),
(14, 4, 4898.99, 5),
(15, 7, 3000, 3),
(15, 9, 1000, 1),
(15, 13, 230, 1),
(15, 11, 5400, 1),
(15, 12, 300, 2),
(16, 13, 230, 1),
(17, 6, 12000, 1),
(17, 15, 430, 2),
(18, 8, 7000, 2),
(18, 7, 3000, 2),
(19, 2, 18000.9, 1),
(20, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(21, 12, 300, 2),
(21, 8, 7000, 1),
(22, 10, 2300.56, 1),
(22, 14, 560, 2),
(23, 5, 17, 5),
(23, 5, 17, 3),
(24, 2, 18000.9, 1);
```

Necesito hacer tres select, uno que filtre las ventas por día, otro por semana y otro por un mes específicos. Que me de como resultado  cantidad y precio total de las ventas por el dia, la semana o mes especificos que les di.

Hasta ahora llevo esta sentencia que me da las ventas y el total de ellas pero no se me ocurre como filtrarla.

```
SELECT
  v.id_venta,
  COUNT(d.id_venta) AS cantidad,
  SUM(d.cantidad * d.precio),
  v.fecha AS f
FROM ventas v
  INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d
    ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta
GROUP BY f
ORDER BY fecha ASC;
```

Estoy usando MySQL

Comment: ¿lo harías basado en algún criterio que ingresaría el usuario, una fecha o solo el número del día, semana o mes?

Comment: Hola @RobertoOrtega, ¿por qué motivo has intentado agrupar por fecha si lo que pretendías era quedarte con determinados registros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes funciones en `mysql` que te premiten calcular dia, semana, mes, ... de un campo fecha.

Por ejemplo para día, semana y mes:

```
SELECT *
FROM ventas v 
INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta 
WHERE DAY(fecha)=1;

SELECT *
FROM ventas v 
INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta 
WHERE WEEK(fecha)=11;

SELECT *
FROM ventas v 
INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta 
WHERE MONTH(fecha)=3;
```

Puedes ver más [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Por favor, corrígeme si me equivoco, pero creo que, en vez de a **filtrar**, te estás refiriendo a **agrupar** por día, semana, mes y año. Lo que sería algo así:

**Resultado diario**

```
SELECT DATE(fecha) dia,
    COUNT(d.id_venta) AS cantidad,
    ROUND(SUM(d.cantidad * d.precio),2) AS importe
  FROM ventas v
    INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d
      ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

**Resultado semanal**

```
SELECT CONCAT(
      YEAR(fecha),'-',LPAD(WEEK(fecha),2,'0')
    ) semana,
    COUNT(d.id_venta) AS cantidad,
    ROUND(SUM(d.cantidad * d.precio),2) AS importe
  FROM ventas v
    INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d
      ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

**Resultado mensual**

```
SELECT CONCAT(
      YEAR(fecha),'-',LPAD(MONTH(fecha),2,'0')
    ) semana,
    COUNT(d.id_venta) AS cantidad,
    ROUND(SUM(d.cantidad * d.precio),2) AS importe
  FROM ventas v
    INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d
      ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

**Resultado anual**

```
SELECT YEAR(fecha) año,
    COUNT(d.id_venta) AS cantidad,
    ROUND(SUM(d.cantidad * d.precio),2) AS importe
  FROM ventas v
    INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d
      ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

**Definiciones**

*Filtrar* o *seleccionar* es una operación algebraica relacional que se implementa en SQL mediante un `WHERE` y que consiste en quedarse con los registros que cumplan una determinada condición.

En cambio, *agrupar* es una operación diferente, vinculada a las funciones de totales `SUM`, `AVG`, `MAX`, `MIN`, etc que, en SQL, se codifica mediante un `GROUP BY`.